# Trying to put each line of an external file inside an array of custom class

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner, instance

I have a text file that has name of all countries and capitals, I made a class called nation, with country name and capital name and I'm trying to take each line of the text file and adding it to the array of nations I created.
My main file is this

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int  SIZE = 205;
        Nation nations [];
        nations = new Nation[SIZE];
        int i = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j < 205 ; j++ ){
            nations[j] = new Nation();
        }
        try {
            File myObj = new File("country.txt");
            Scanner myReader = new Scanner(myObj);
            while (myReader.hasNextLine()) {
                i++;
                nations[i].setcountry(myReader.nextLine());

            }
            myReader.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("An error occurred.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(nations[1].getCountry());
        System.out.println(nations[3].getCountry());
        System.out.println(nations[5].getCountry());
        System.out.println(nations[100].getCountry());
    }
    }
```

My class is pretty simple there shouldn't be anything wrong with it

```
public class Nation {
    private static String country = "empty";
    private static String capital = "empty";
    public Nation(){
        country = "empty";
        capital = "empty";
    }
    public Nation(String coountry, String caapital){
        country = coountry;
        capital = caapital;
    }

    public void setCapital(String capital){
        this.capital = capital;
    }
    public void setcountry(String country){
        this.country = country;
    }
    public String getCapital(){return this.capital;}
    public String getCountry(){return this.country;}

}
```

My text file is something like this:
Country_name       Capital_Name

in my head the output should be "index_country_name index_capital_name" but every single output is
Zimbabwe Harare
Zimbabwe Harare
Zimbabwe Harare
Zimbabwe Harare

which is the final country in the text file,
I also added a bunch of redundant code in hopes that it might fix the issue so sorry if the code is extra ugly

Comment: please show at least some lines of your file

Comment: right off the top, you should switch the lines `i++;` and `nations[i].setcountry(myReader.nextLine());` you aren't assigning anything to nations[0] right now. and more importantly if there is 205 lines in your file you are assigning your last line to memory outside your array

Answer (score 2):

your country and capital must not be static in class Nation, since that way they got overwritten every time for the class. And since any instance uses the static variable as if it where an instance variable, all instances see the last change. so just remove static there. And afterwards clean up the remaining code.

Comment: yup that was it thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Your *Nation* class is using *static* variables.

```java
private static String country = "empty";
private static String capital = "empty";
```

Use a *[record class](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/language/records.html)*, instead.

```java
record Nation(String coountry, String caapital) { }
```

```java
List<Nation> nations = new ArrayList<>();
try (Scanner myReader = new Scanner(new File("country.txt"))) {
    String[] s;
    while (myReader.hasNextLine()) {
        s = myReader.nextLine().split(" ");
        nations.add(new Nation(s[0], s[1]));
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("An error occurred.");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println(nations.get(1).coountry());
System.out.println(nations.get(3).coountry());
System.out.println(nations.get(5).coountry());
System.out.println(nations.get(100).coountry());
```